# Openshift "template" resource is getting recreated after deletion

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am deleting a custom template `httpd-example` using below command:

```
oc delete template httpd-example -n openshift
```

However, the template object is getting recreated after deletion.

```
oc get template -n openshift | grep httpd
```

I am not able to understand how the template is getting recreated again after deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `httpd-example` template is not a "custom template"; it's one that is provided by OpenShift "out of the box". On a fresh OpenShift (4.14.x) install, the `openshift` namespace contains 50 templates, including the `httpd-example` template:

```
$ oc -n openshift get template httpd-example
NAME            DESCRIPTION                                                                        PARAMETERS     OBJECTS
httpd-example   An example Apache HTTP Server (httpd) application that serves static content....   10 (3 blank)   5
```

These templates are managed by the `openshift-samples` operator. If we delete one of these managed templates, we see:

```
$ kubectl -n openshift-cluster-samples-operator logs -l name=cluster-samples-operator -f
Defaulted container "cluster-samples-operator" out of: cluster-samples-operator, cluster-samples-operator-watch
.
.
.
time="2024-02-06T04:02:27Z" level=info msg="going to recreate deleted managed sample template/httpd-example"
time="2024-02-06T04:02:27Z" level=info msg="created template httpd-example"
```

If you are working with custom templates, create them in a different namespace, and leave the `openshift` namespace to managed resources.

---

Configuration of the cluster samples operator is described in [the documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.14/openshift_images/configuring-samples-operator.html).

You can instruct the cluster samples operator to stop managing a particular template by setting the `skippedTemplates` option in the operator configuration:

```
oc patch config.samples.operator.openshift.io cluster \
  --type=merge  --patch '{"spec": {"skippedTemplates": ["httpd-example"]}}'
```

With this configuration in place, we can delete the `httpd-example` template:

```
oc -n openshift delete template httpd-example
```

And see in the cluster samples operator log:

```
cluster-samples-operator-64f49fbf5c-2f98t cluster-samples-operator time="2024-02-06T04:39:14Z" level=info msg="watch event httpd-example in skipped list for template"
```

---

You can stop the cluster samples operator from managing **all** resources by setting its `managementState` to `Removed`.

```
oc patch config.samples.operator.openshift.io cluster \
  --type=merge  --patch '{"spec": {"managementState": "Removed"}}'
```

This will cause the operator to remove *all* managed resources (templates and imagestreams). Setting the `managementState` back to `Managed` will restore all the managed resources.

Comment: thanks for the details. I get your point on `httpd-example` being a managed template. Still, how can I delete it without effecting other templates?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more information about the samples operator.

Comment: Oh, interesting, it looks like you can set `skippedTemplates` value in the configuration to skip specific templates. Let me try that and update the answer.